# Writing embeded ruby in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `autofill.js.erb` file in which should change value of input field with id `request_mobile` to `@client.mobile`, where `@client.mobile` is defined in autofill method. So i guess it should be accessible in `autofill.js.erb` file. both files are in one view folder.

```
$("#request_mobile").val("<%= escape_javascript @client.mobile %>");
```

But what i get is:

```
$("#request_mobile").val("");
```

So my ruby is not embedded int JS or something like that. What is the proper way of writing `js.erb` files.

Also trying :

```
$("#request_mobile").val("<%= @client.mobile %>");
```

doesn't help

Comment: What is the value of `@client.mobile` in this instance?

Comment: What do you mean "both files are in one view folder"?

Comment: What you've written *is* the proper way, and the Ruby is definitely being embedded or you wouldn't see `""` in the output. You would see the original string of Ruby source code between `<%=` and `%>`. At this point, it's pretty clearly a case of `@client.mobile` not containing what you think it contains.

Comment: @meagar, i am using ajax, so in my view i have autofill.js.erb which is executed in respond_to autofill method in controller

Comment: Check your web console logs. It will clear what js code server is returning.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry all, that was my fault. Actually everything works fine. I just didn't notice that in my db actually all mobile fields are empty.

```html
$("#request_mobile").val("<%= escape_javascript @client.name %>");
```

```html
$("#request_mobile").val("<%=  @client.name %>");
```

Both work fine.